# Generar json Con datos aleatorios

Tags: json, ios, xcode, datos, generador

Hola como puede generar un fichero json de datos falsos, escribiendo la estructura de objetos anidados. Gracias

Ejemplo
Hospital, tiene dos campos nombre y dirección, dentro de hospital tiene salas, con campos nombre sala, capacidad, etc, y Reservas con campos día, hora, descripción, sa

Comment: Te he encontrado un generador de código a partir de un esquema. Seguro que te es de ayuda [json-schema-faker](https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md)